# jQuery: event.preventdefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yii

If I create the click events and their handler on my own, it is no problem for me to execute event.preventdefault() at the right place. But if there is an element, which already has registered click events and corresponding handler, I want to deactivate its further working (e.g. submitting) in a certain case.

This is the example:

There is a submit button on the page, with registered click elements (maybe about hundred validation routines.. ) and a variable (al) with a certain value. Be the instantaneous value of this variable = 5 (it is not the desired certain case -> with value = 3).

**HTML**

```
// other form elements
<input type="submit" name="next" value="go"/>
```

**JavaScript with jQuery**

```
var al = 3;

$("input[type='submit'][name='next']").click(
    function(event) {
        if (al != 3) {
            alert (al+': Not OK');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            alert ('OK');
        }
    }
);
```

In this example I cannot prevent the form is being submitted. What is my mistake?

EDIT: event.preventDefault ist not the problem, sublime (my editor) corrects it anyway.

----- I WANT TO SIMPLIFY THE QUESTION ---------

That is a SubmitButon (this time from yii in the original context):

**VIEW**

```
echo CHtml::submitButton(
Yii::t ('Somethin', 'next'),
    array( 
        'name' => 'next', 
        'onclick' => "checkDetails()"
    ));
```

**JS**

```
checkDetails() {
    PREVENT_SUBMITTING
}
```

How should PREVENT_SUBMITTING look? What would prevent submitting in this case, without any condition?

Comment: Use :  event.preventDefault();

Comment: Please open the console once and check for errors like **`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'preventdefault'`**

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Not the type is the problem, I've edited the original question.

Comment: @E2B Have you actually checked what the value of `al` is when that code runs?

Comment: yes, I did (in my case it is the length of a value of an input text field..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have a working solution:

**VIEW**

```
echo PHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('Something', 'next'),
    array( 
        'name' => 'next',
        'onclick' => "return checkDetails(event)",
    )
);
```

**jQuery**

```
function checkDetails (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue =false; // for IE
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
event.preventdefault();
```

to

```
event.preventDefault();
```

you have to write the "D" as capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways

```
$("input[type='submit'][name='next']").click(
    function(event) {
        if (al != 3) {
            alert (al+': Not OK');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            alert ('OK');
        }
    }
);
```

or

```
$("input[type='submit'][name='next']").click(
    function(event) {
        if (al != 3) {
            alert (al+': Not OK');
            return false;
        } else {
            alert ('OK');
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: It should be noted that `return false;` also cancels event bubbling which can cause separate problems. Also, there is no need to `return true;`

Comment: Would you explain the difference between two?

Comment: return false basically is the same as calling event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation which as @RoryMcCrossan states stops event bubbling which in theory when the structure is div<-ul<-li the li is clicked and the event is passed from li to ul to div element you can find a detailed explaination here http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: I'll try it with `return false`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='submit'][name='next']").click(
    function(event) {
        if (al != 3) {
            alert (al+': Not OK');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            alert ('OK');
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Change `event.preventDefault();`

```
$("input[type='submit'][name='next']").click(
    function(event) {
        if (al != 3) {
            alert (al+': Not OK');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            alert ('OK');
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to use `.off()` instead of `.preventDefault()`. I needed to intercept and block one event handler while still allowing the main click event to bubble up. Might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from this problem I ll suggestion you to separate the validation part e. g

Add another  form input e.g `proceed`

```
<input type="hidden" name="proceed" value="0"/>
<input type="submit" name="next" value="go"/>
```

Add custom validation method

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateSteps", function(value, element) {
                return value == 3 ? false : true;
            }, "*");
```

Add validation rule to you form

```
$("#your_form_id").validate({
      rules: {          
          "proceed": {
              validateSteps: true
          }
      },
      messages: {
          "proceed": {
              validateSteps: "custom message"
          }
      }
  });
```

You have to set proper value to `proceed` input field before. This way you do not need to wade through event issues. And its more customizable e.g if you have ten steps with different validation requirements on each step